# set input fields if select change

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I have the following sample data:

```
books = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: Harry Potter,
  description: test1
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: Forest Gump,
  description: test2
 }
]
```

JSP

```
<select onchange="bookLib.changeBook()">
  <c:forEach var="book" items="${books }">
      <option value="${book.id}">
          <c:out value="${book.name}"/>
      </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>

<input type="TEXT" id="descr" readonly/>
```

When "select" is changed, I need to set ${book.description} in the text input which is identified with id "descr".

I need to implement this in the function `bookLib.changeBook().js` with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select onchange="bookLib.changeBook(this);">
  <c:forEach var="book" items="${books }">
      <option value="${book.id}" data-description="${book.descripton}">
          <c:out value="${book.name}"/>
      </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>

<input type="TEXT" id="descr" readonly/>

function changeBook(select) {
    $("#descr").val($(select).find("option:selected").attr("data-description"));
}
```

Alternatively, if you have no control over the signature of `changeBook`:

```
<select id="books" onchange="bookLib.changeBook()">
  <c:forEach var="book" items="${books }">
      <option value="${book.id}" data-description="${book.descripton}">
          <c:out value="${book.name}"/>
      </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>

<input type="TEXT" id="descr" readonly/>

function changeBook() {
    $("#descr").val($("#books option:selected").attr("data-description"));
}
```